# Can I make the dashboard the default overview?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure devOps, there are 3 section in the `Overview` service of a project: `Summary`, `Dashboard` and `Wiki`.

When I click on the `Overview` button, it defaults to the `Summary`section. Is it possible to change that for the `Dashboard instead ?

Comment: Not without a client-side redirect.

Comment: thanks, if you set it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the left-hand menu is only editable via extensibility. You may wish to add a link to the Summary page `.md` to link to the dashboards, or you could create a client-side redirect.